# EGit Ignore / Android

Tags: android, git, bitbucket, egit

I've got a .gitignore file and I've also used EGit to "untrack" and "ignore" files in the bin directory of my Android project.  Nonetheless, whenever I do a commit, these three files are always there (with their gray ignore X icon) but automatically CHECKED. Why?

The three files are classes.dex, myproject.apk, resources.ap_

How in the world can I make it so these are actually ignored and not auto-checked on a commit?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you examined what's actually in the repo? Look at the gitignore to make sure the files are listed, see if the files are actually tracked (not just a spurious check-mark).

Answer (score 3):

robinr is right, git ignore even sometimes worsens the situation.

You can do two things:

1) Remove the files you were trying to untrack from .gitignore first. After that you do untrack->commit. You can choose to git ignore them after this.

OR

2) [Assume unchanged](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Menu_Actions), which flags the files as if you never touched them after and achieves what you were trying to do (ignore/untrack).

Answer (score 1):

You could explicitly state these files in your .gitignore file. Or you could ignore all .dex, .apk, and .ap_ files by adding this to your .gitignore:

```
*.dex
*.apk
*.ap_
```

Answer (score 1):

If a file has already been added, it does not help to put them into .gitignore. You also
need to tell git not to track the file anymore (git rm)